# how to store string of numbers into unsigned integer in C

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

Actually, I have to convert from command arguments which are three strings to bit field(three unsigned integers inside). This program is going to convert from bits into float. I firstly thought about using array to store the three arguments,but I don't really know how to convert from array to unsigned int. Should I just use atoi to change arg into int and then directly into unsigned int?  It doesn't word on my computer. Got no idea.

```
Union32 getBits(char *sign, char *exp, char *frac)
{
    Union32 new;

   // this line is just to keep gcc happy
   // delete it when you have implemented the function
   //new.bits.sign = new.bits.exp = new.bits.frac = 0;

   new.bits.sign = *(unsigned int *)atoi(sign);
   new.bits.exp = *(unsigned int *)atoi(exp);
   new.bits.frac = *(unsigned int *)atoi(frac);
   //int i ;
   //int balah[8] = {};
   //for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
   //balah[i] = sign[i];
   //}

   //int j ;
   //int bili[23] = {};
   //for(j = 0; j < 23; j++){
      //bili[j] = sign[j];
   //}

   //convert array into unsigned integer?
   printf("%u %u %u\n", new.bits.sign, new.bits.exp, new.bits.frac);


   // convert char *sign into a single bit in new.bits

   // convert char *exp into an 8-bit value in new.bits

   // convert char *frac into a 23-bit value in new.bits
enter code here
   return new;
}
```

The following are the details about the typedef and unions that needed in this program, also the four functions in this program.

```
typedef uint32_t Word;

struct _float {
   // define bit_fields for sign, exp and frac
   // obviously they need to be larger than 1-bit each
   // and may need to be defined in a different order
   unsigned int sign:1, exp:8, frac:23;
};
typedef struct _float Float32;

union _bits32 {
   float   fval;  // interpret the bits as a float
   Word    xval;  // interpret as a single 32-bit word
   Float32 bits;  // manipulate individual bits
};
typedef union _bits32 Union32;

void    checkArgs(int, char **);
Union32 getBits(char *, char *, char *);
char   *showBits(Word, char *);
int     justBits(char *, int);
```

getBits asks us to convert bits into float,
and showBits asks us to convert float into bits.

Comment: Give me a code example of the use of the function `getBits`. I'll think to call it as: `getBits("-1","+10","1.2349")` to represent the number -1.2349E+10, it's correct?

Comment: You used (unsigned int *) where you have to use (unsigned int). But if I understood your idea the code is not correctly implemented.

Comment: How is `Union32` defined!? You cannot store separete value into a `union`, you have to use a `struct`.

Comment: @SirJoBlack I do not think that "1.2349" represents the integer value. Your example is bad. Give a more sane one.

Comment: @SirJoBlack probably it union of the bitfield struct and another 32 bits data. As you see there are two dots which implies a nested struct or union

Comment: My question is the use of the function! How do you use the function? Give me a real example of a call to this function.

Comment: We need the definition of the type `Union32` to understand the open points.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the correct typedefs in your code:

```
   new.bits.sign = (unsigned int)atoi(sign);
   new.bits.exp = (unsigned int)atoi(exp);
   new.bits.frac = (unsigned int)atoi(frac);
```